# Detect SKSpriteNode finished moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm fairly new with **SpriteKit** and I can't figure this one out. When you run an `SKAction` to move a `SKSpriteNode`, you can add blocks as completion handlers or even execute `SKActions` in sequence. But after several attempts I found out that the sequence or the handler are called after the Node is moved, but before it reaches its destination. I'm trying to figure out a handy way to detect when the movement is finally completed (and the Node reached its destination).

I'm moving the `SKSpriteNode` with the following method:

```
+ (SKAction *)moveTo:(CGPoint)location
        duration:(NSTimeInterval)sec
```

**EDIT** (code)

In the following code I have some SKSpriteNodes in moveArray that need to be moved. I create a move action for each of them. In the completion handler I make them disappear. I have a actionArray that groups this actions and then is ran as a group (all the objects need to move at the same time). I need to update the score of the game after this move is completed. This is done at the end. But what I see, is that the score increases after the Nodes start moving, but before they reached their destination.

```
NSMutableArray *actionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(SKSpriteNode* r in moveArray){

    SKAction *move = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(r.position.x,-20.0f) duration: 1.0f];

    SKAction* action = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [r runAction:move completion:^{
            [r removeFromParent];
        }];
    }];

    [actionArray addObject:action];

}

SKAction *groupAction = [SKAction group:actionArray];
[self runAction:groupAction completion:^(void){
     self.score++;
 }];
```

Comment: When you put a completion block inside of runaction it gets called when the animation is finished. This isn't working for you? Can you post an example where that doesn't work?

Comment: Your issue is that when you use runBlock its expecting an arbitrary block of code. It doesn't really work with a completion block. RunBlock isn't an animation. It doesn't have any particular duration

Comment: @hamobi Thanks. Your answer pointed me in the right direction.